# Send command 'Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride' does not work in chrome.debugger

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I writing an extension to emulate the mobile device whenever user click on extension icon. This is just the first version of extension so that everything was hardcoded.

I basically attached successfully to Chrome current tab but I do not know why my commands does not work as expected. I using Chrome **version 79** with **protocolversion command is 1.3**. The steps I currently implemented are:

1. **Attach** to current chrome tab.
2. Using **Browser.getVersion** to checking whether I am using correct protocol version
3. Using **Emulation.canEmulate** to make sure chrome can emulate mobile device.
4. Using **Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride** to clear all of metrics if any.
5. Using **Emulation.setUserAgentOverride** to override current user agent.
6. Using **Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride** to emulate mobile device.
7. Enable touch event using **Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled** to emulate mobile event.

Here is code of above steps:

```
function EmulateMobileDevice(tabId) {

var protocolVersion = '1.3';
chrome.debugger.attach({
    tabId: tabId
}, protocolVersion, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }

    // Browser.getVersion
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Browser.getVersion", {}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    // Emulation.canEmulate
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Emulation.canEmulate", {}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    // Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride", {}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        // Emulation.setUserAgentOverride
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
            tabId: tabId
        }, "Emulation.setUserAgentOverride", {
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1',
            acceptLanguage: 'en',
            platform: 'mobile'
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: tabId
            }, "Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride", {
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                deviceScaleFactor: 0,
                mobile: true,
                screenOrientation: { type: 'portraitPrimary', angle: 1}
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);

                // Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                    tabId: tabId
                }, "Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled", {
                    enabled: true
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }); 
            });
        });
    }); });}
```

I refered the same idea [here](https://github.com/paulirish/emulation-popup-ext/blob/master/app/scripts/background.js) implemented by @paulirish but he demonstrated in protocol version 1.1 which was deprecated for now. And I also read the document from [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Emulation) for protocol version 1.3.
Unfortunately I can not get it work.

Here is the screenshot I logged in background script of above method.

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: You can [listen to protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#remote) while performing device emulation in devtools manually and inspect the commands and their parameters. I guess you should specify actual width/height, not 0.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, I tried by it still not working. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: @vietvoquoc did you mange to make it work? i have the same use case

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reload the page after modifying DeviceMetricsOverride
using

> chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);

Answer (score 0):

If you can brief about what you want to do with your code that would help,

As of now, code would just show the tab as it is because when width, height and deviceScaleFactor are set to '0'(zero) it would set the website to the default size, but since you specified mobile true default scroll bar would change(It may hide based on your css).